# Apache will not start error - error in cmd please

Tags: apache

```
Diese Eingabeforederung nicht des Running beenden
bitte erst bei einem gewollten Shutdown schliessen
Please close this command only for Shutdown
Apache 2 is starting . . .
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 35 of C:/Program Files (x86)/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: server root must be a valid directory.

Apache konnte nicht gestartet werden
Apache could not be started
Press any key to continue...
```

This is what I get the CMD prompt... Can someone help?

Comment: Hi Alexander, welcome to Stack Overflow!  This site is for questions related to code that you have written or are intending to write - see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).  Another site in the StackExchange network, [sf], would be a more appropriate forum for your question.  I have voted to have your question migrated there, but that won't happen automatically until another 4 voters concur or a moderator intervenes.  Good luck!

Comment: I'd be curious to understand why you originally tagged a problem with Apache using a MySQL tag.  Accurate tagging will get your questions read by people who may be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

> Syntax error on line 35 of C:/Program Files (x86)/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: server root must be a valid directory

I suggest that you:

- Open the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`;
- Inspect line 35; and
- Change the value of [`ServerRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serverroot) to a valid directory.

Comment: And then check the other lines in the file to see whether they make sense.  In case of doubt, leave alone, but check them at least.